# Difference of two postive semi definite (psd) matrices

Tags: matrices

Given two psd matrices $A$ and $B$, under what condition $A-B$ is also a psd matrix ? Both A and B are full-rank and of the form $T^HT$.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so one quick condition i could think of is $\lambda_{\text{min}}(\pmb{A}) \geq \lambda_{\text{max}}(\pmb{B})$ because for any vector $\pmb{z}$, the quantity $\pmb{z}^T(\pmb{A} - \pmb{B})\pmb{z}$ should remain positive for any $\pmb{z}$. Keep in mind that $\pmb{z}^T\pmb{A}\pmb{z} \geq 0$ and $\pmb{z}^T\pmb{B}\pmb{z}  \geq 0$ because both are psds
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pmb{z}^T(\pmb{A} - \pmb{B})\pmb{z} \geq 0 
&\\ \Rightarrow \text{min}_{\pmb{z}} \pmb{z}^T(\pmb{A} - \pmb{B})\pmb{z} \geq 0 
&\\ \Rightarrow \text{min}_{\pmb{z}} \pmb{z}^T\pmb{A}\pmb{z} - \text{max}_{\pmb{z}} \pmb{z}^T\pmb{B}\pmb{z}\geq 0 
&\\ \Rightarrow \lambda_{\text{min}}(\pmb{A}) - \lambda_{\text{max}}(\pmb{B}) \geq 0 
&\\ \Rightarrow \lambda_{\text{min}}(\pmb{A}) \geq \lambda_{\text{max}}(\pmb{B})  
\end{split}
\end{equation}